# Can't boot up: snd_hda_intel no codecs found!

Tags: boot, drivers, dual-boot, nvidia, 22.04

This is the third time that I see this error after updating Ubuntu 22.04 from the software updater (I usually do it on the terminal), and when it asks to reboot. The message says:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p6: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p6: clean, 386606/15261691 files, 6474386/61035264 blocks
[    7.217639] snd_hda_intel 0000:17:00.6: no codecs found!
```

It gets stuck in there and won't boot up.

**Software**

- Windows 10
- Ubuntu 22.04

**Hardware**

- AMD Ryzen 9 7900X
- MSI PRO X670-P
- Samsung 970 EVO Plus 1 TB PCIe NVMe M.2
- Gigabyte GeForce GTX 1070Ti

**Attempts**

So far I have tried:

- run `fsck -f` from the recovery screen on my partitions formatted on EXT4, but I could not as they were mounted and I couldn't `umount` them.
- run `fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1pX` (where `X` refers to the same partitions) from a bootable ubuntu, which only got rid of the `recovering journal` bit
- edit the grub by adding `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the `Linux` line

None of the above fixed anything. As far as I know this is an issue with the graphic drivers, and I saw in the list of software to update in the updater mentioned at the beginning that were unticked, so they didn't update.

The previous two times it was with different hardware (also a GeForce, but an older one), same version of the OS, and I just decided to ditch the system and reinstall, but this time I'd rather not bother doing it and fix it instead.

**Update**

I saw another post where there was suggested to set the `Linux`entry in the grub to `nomodeset` instead of `quiet splash`. I did that, and now I can boot Ubuntu. However, now I have no sound and the scroll is not as smooth as it used to be, and I'm not sure if, after turning this off it will boot normally or will just update that entry and come back to the same error.

**Update 2**

As I suspected, after rebooting it will edit that config and set it back to `quiet splash`. I tried to run

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525 nvidia-dkms-525
```

But, as said in the installation process, it would ask me for a password after restarting. The problem is that the password didn't match (I typed literally the same, it was just not printing characters).

Can someone please give some advice on how to deal with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The password issue probably come from your keyboard layout being different from the default qwerty.

Try using a very simple password with keys that don't change between layouts.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue as you and compiled a list of solutions for issues I have ran into. This is likely all due to dual booting Ubuntu and Windows with this AMD setup.

I am going to copy/paste my own notes below. Hopefully this helps you debug your setup. I will update my answer with my BIOS version next time I boot up my system.

## Hardware

- CPU - AMD Ryzen 9 7950X - 16 Core - 32 Thread
- GPU - NVIDIA 4090 (PNY XLR8)
- RAM - Kingston Fury Beast RGB White 128GB
- MOBO - MSI MAG B650 Tomahawk WiFi Gaming Motherboard (AM5 Socket)

## Software

- Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS

  - Lambda Stack
- Windows 11 Home

Each OS is on a different M.2 SSD.

## Problems

### Issue

- Linux OS will not start up.
- If Linux is not the first boot option, and you select it in the boot menu, when prompted with the Ubuntu startup options and select the default generic kernel, you will arrive at a screen that displays:

```
[...] hub 8-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)
[...] /dev/nvme1n1p2: clean ...
[...] snd_hda_intel 0000:11:00.6 no codecs found!
```

- You cannot get past this screen and a power off is required.

**Quick Solution**

- When you are at the Ubuntu kernel boot options, select change boot kernel, then select one of the other kernels in Recovery Mode.
- Once the Recovery Mode GUI loads, select exit.
- Then the user login screen will finally load.

**HOWEVER**

- If using the solution from above, the NVIDIA CUDA driver will not load.
- You can verify that it is installed when looking at the Additional Drivers application as well as running:

```
$ nvcc --version
```

However, when you run:

```
$ nvidia-smi
```

It will say driver not loaded/found.

**Full Solution (this is wild)**

- Change the boot order in the BIOS to boot Ubuntu first, then Windows.
- You might still hit a screen that gives the "snd_hda_intel" error, but wait a few seconds and you should get to the user login screen.
- Check if things are working by running the "nvidia-smi" command.

### Issue

- Wifi driver will not boot up in Linux.

**Solution**

- Disable fast boot in Windows 11 power settings.

### Issue

- If using the system as a server without a monitor connected, the internal WIFI card and/or driver will not function.
- If you reconnect a monitor, there will be no ability to select or even turn on WIFI. In my case, there was bizarre behavior where mouse movements and keystrokes were also extremely slow.

**Solution**

- Plug a cable into the back of the GPU. Doesn't even need to be connected to a monitor. Just plug a display port cable in and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I am just experiencing the same issues. However, I have a bit of a different situation.

1. I updated my hardware, and I also got a MSI X670 PRO and a new AMD CPU
2. I then updated 20.04 to 22.04 and it worked all fine (without reinstalling ubuntu after hardware upgrade)
3. While it still worked, however I had 1 situation where it either crashed or didn't boot (don't exactly remember, but it was "fishy"). Still, apart from that 1 situation, everything fine
4. Today I can no longer boot the system, and I get the same output you posted above

Between 3) and 4) I updated the BIOS to 7D67v19 because since I got the mainboard, it would *always* show a big fat "CPU FAN ERROR" screen upon boot, and I wanted it to go away. And indeed, after installing 7D67v19 the CPU fan error went away.
Whats weird about the BIOS "update" is that the version which came out on 2023-06-12 - the 7D67v19 - seems to be *older* than what was previously installed, according to the version number.

But now it does not boot ubuntu. I don't know if this is related, since after the BIOS update I didnt use ubuntu for a while, so I just found out today that it no longer boots.

I am about to update BIOS to 7D67v1A2(Beta version) and see what happens.

Good to know you are facing similar issues. I was afraid it was caused by me upgrading the hardware (CPU + RAM + mainboard + GPU) without reinstalling ubuntu. But as it seems it has nothing to do with that.

[edit] Did not help. Same as you I also tried `nomodeset` instead of `quiet splash`, and indeed I can now boot into ubuntu, but I am left without sound. So no idea at which point the system broke, and what can be done to repair it.

[edit2] In fact, now I remember what changed between 3) and 4). I actually replaced my nVIDIA RTX 4800 with a RTX 4090 card, which was not supported by the driver I had installied (530.41.03). I have just now updated to 535.54.03 and everything seems to be working fine again. Graphics driver works, sound works, system boots.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change a major system component?  This is how I got my Ubuntu booting again.

I had these same issues after having to change my motherboard.  The problem was that I had to enroll a new key into my secure boot settings.  If you use Ubuntu with secure boot and change a major part of the system, you may need to enroll a new key to the MOK.

Boot into recovery mode and continue to see if you can boot to the desktop from recovery mode.  Because I had a new motherboard, I had to fix my network settings first from the command line with nmcli, but this may not be necessary.

Run a sudo upgrade (this may ask to add the key for secure boot) and enter a password.  If, for some reason, this doesn't work the first time or you need to do this again, this is the command to add a key for the secure boot:

```
sudo update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key
```

After you restart, your BIOS will ask you about a new key. Choose "enroll key" and enroll the new key using your created password.  The system should now boot normally.

This is what worked for me; I hope it helps.  Didn't want just to fix my PC and not let anyone know how I got it fixed, so decided to post this.